# Table show/hide breaking when using it with table property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to hide and show a table using jquery which is working. My issue is I also need to check if this table is visible or not in the codebehind so I can say if it is visible then validate these fields. And I also want the table to not be visible on pageload.

On my PageLoad when I add the following code the javascript stops working

```
table1.Visible = false;
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkbox1").change(function () {
        $("#table1").toggle();
    });
})

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" />
<table id="table1">
Hiddent Fields
</table>
```

Comment: try debugging , put alert('test') to test if change event is triggered,may be conflicts don't let jQuery do his job

Comment: I would suggest using css for table. Instead of `table1.Visible = false;`. Use `<table id="table1" style="display:none">`. Remember, visible=false would not render the table at all!

Comment: Thats fine afzalulh i dont mind using css however in my code behind how would i check to see if the table is visible or not before i do something?

Comment: @Jay - Pls see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my 2 cents:

In markup:

```
<table id="table1" runat="server">
```

In Page_Load:

```
table1.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

And when you want to check if the table is invisible:

```
if(table1.Style["display"] == "none")
{
    // Do what you need to 
}
```

You will have full control of the table in jquery as well as in code behind.

Comment: This is what I want but the if statement you wrote does not work any ideas?

Comment: Cleaned up the code. I have edited my answer. did you try with if(table1.Style["display"] == "none")? I have tested it and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`hidden`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) selector.

```
// Matches all elements that are hidden
$('element:hidden')
```

And the [`visible`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) selector

```
// Matches all elements that are visible.
$('element:visible')
```

or

You can use `.is(':visible')` to test if something is visible and `.is(':hidden')` to test for the opposite:

- http://api.jquery.com/is/
- http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

to hide on page load you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#table1').hide();
});
```

or using `css`

```
#table1{ display:none; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2cSJz/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table1").hide();
     $("#checkbox1").change(function () {
        $("#table1").toggle();
    });
})
```

Comment: His problem is that he uses id to select checkbox instead of name attribute , that's all. Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/FCmve/

Comment: my solution works until i add table1.visbile = false on pageload in codebehind. The table stays hidden and jquery does not take effect

Comment: @Jay don't add that code instead use css `#table1{ display:none; } `

Comment: if i do that then how would i test to see if the table visible property is true or false in code behind? Is there another way i should check for this?

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ncRGp/6/)**

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table1").hide();
     $("#checkbox1").change(function () {
        $("#table1").toggle();
    });
})
```

and specify `id="checkbox1"`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
<table id="table1">
    <th>Hidden things</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to access element using his **id** (**#checkbox1**) instead of his **name** , so your problem is that your change event is never triggered.
Change your selector to use `name='checkbox1'` :

```
  $("input[name='checkbox1']").change(function () {});
```

Or add `id='checkbox1'` to your input:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1"  />
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/FCmve/)**

Comment: Sorry that was a typo that is not my issue. My jquery works it stops working if i decided to add on pageload table1.visbile = false

Comment: replace it by js code: $("#table1").hide(); or show us code to know your issue.Check also console to see what happens

Comment: i showed you the code essential I will be checking if table1.visible = false then do something. But if I am not setting the visible property I am setting the css propertery how can I achieve that